# Can Query Builder in SAS EG be used to output fixed-width columns?

Tags: sas, output, column-width

thanks for any help! I’ll try to be concise.

I am new to SAS and have inherited a SAS run that outputs a table with 15 columns, which I export as an excel file and deliver.

The recipient would now like it as a .txt file with fixed-width columns, and has provided the character limit/width for each column.

Is this something that can be done in query builder, so I can just query the existing table rather than modifying the code in the run? I tried filling the field for ‘Length’ when you add a column to query builder, but it did not have the desired result.

Comment: Not within QUERY BUILDER but an EXPORT task for fixed width files should exist. It's also very trivial to write a data step to generate a fixed width file: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/txt-output-with-fixed-columns/td-p/485190 or this one https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-do-i-write-out-a-fixed-format-file-in-sas/

Comment: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/egdoccdc/8.1/egug/n0mvg67r18evf8n1wt42aurlv64l.htm#p08stx0bj1cdt5n1t16z5hw5oio6 Look at the options in Step 2, one should support Fixed Width but not sure how you can tell it the specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried the Export File step option, but there were no options within Export File that allowed me to adjust column format (or really any format). The step 5 in that list—viewing code—did not appear for me. It went right from output destination to confirmation of choices.

I am currently attempting both of the options in your first answer, but am getting an access error when trying to save the .txt output file. I’ve reached out to my admins about it.

Comment: Query Builder does have an option to set Length for a column. I can also format a column in Query Builder and have it use $CHARx format. I tried $CHAR25 to make the column 25 chars long, but in the results and the exported .txt file, the file did not have the extra padding I asked for (the 12-character entries still ended right after the 12th character, with a comma at the end before the next column). I’m confused as to what the LENGTH and FORMAT options in Query Builder are supposed to do.

Comment: Fixed width files typically don't have comma's or delimiters, that's the point of having a fixed position. It sounds like you picked the wrong output option.

Comment: I did try changing it to space delimited, but it still did not have the necessary padding. The EXPORT FILE step gave the following file options: .sas7bdat, .xslx, .csv, .txt, .tab, and space-delimited .txt. Is one of these options ideal?

Comment: .txt is the only remotely nearest option.

Comment: FYI - if you ask on Communities.sas.com the developers will answer the question, I don't have EG to test anything to show you how to do it, they will for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it